# How to test Camel-Mail component?

Tags: java, smtp, apache-camel, integration-testing

I have a situation where I am using [Camel-Mail](http://camel.apache.org/mail) to generate emails from a backend process. Some of the time, the email is sent and some of the time the email does not get sent. I have added logging statements to verify that the Camel-Mail component *is* being executed in the cases where the emails aren't going out. So something is going wrong with my route or the Camel-Mail component itself.

In a perfect world, I'd like to do a full dump of the entire SMTP request that Camel-Mail generates, so I could see all SMTP properties/settings, connection details, etc. that its using to connect to the SMTP server *just before it goes to make the request.* I'd also like to make sure that Camel-Mail isn't catching/ignoring any SMTP/network exceptions, or that it's not logging them to a place where I'll never receive the log statements.

**How can I accomplish this from Java?** How can I see:

- If Camel is throwing/catching/ignoring any exceptions that never bubble up to my app?; or
- If Camel is unable to connect to the SMTP server in some cases; or
- If Camel is not setting certain SMTP properties in some cases, which causes the SMTP server to ignore or drop the request?

Comment: Did you check the spam folder? I know this sounds silly but that might be the case. Also if you could add the camel route to the question we would be able to look at it. The current question does not have enough detail on it to answer it properly.

Comment: If there is an exception or error, the usual behaviour of most components is to throw it. Can you verify you are not doing `onException(Exception.class).handled().etc...` some place? Maybe even please post your routebuilder code.

Comment: I could also say that we are using the camel mail component with 2.10 without problems for a long time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap your call to the mail endpoint using doTry().

```
from("direct:start")
.doTry()
    .to("smtp://matt@stackoverflow.com")
.doCatch(Exception.class)
    .to("log:somethings wrong")
.doFinally()
    .to("mock:finally")
.end();
```

Obviously do something more useful in the .doCatch block. This will catch any exceptions that are thrown by the mail component.

Update: Adding Spring DSL implementation:

```
<from uri="direct:start"/>
<doTry>
    <to uri="smtp://matt@stackoverflow.com"/>
    <doCatch>
        <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
        <to uri="log:somethings wrong"/>
    </doCatch>
    <doFinally>
        <to uri="mock:finally"/>
    </doFinally>
</doTry>
```

Here's the link to the documentation - http://camel.apache.org/try-catch-finally.html

Comment: Thanks @Matthew Wilson (+1) - however I'm using Spring XML. How would your code snippet translate to XML? Thanks again!

Comment: Updated my answer to include the Spring DSL implementation